# Ошибка при создании SQL запроса

Tags: mysql

При выполнении запроса выводится ошибка

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, discipline, exam, student WHERE exam.stud_id = student.stud_id AND ' at line 2

Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT group.index_group, discipline.name_disc, COUNT(*), SUM(value)
FROM  group, discipline, exam, student
WHERE exam.stud_id = student.stud_id AND
exam.disc_id = discipline.disc_id AND
exam.value IS NOT NULL AND
exam.value > 2
GROUP BY group.index_group, discipline.name_disc
```

Вот используемые таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discipline` (
`disc_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name_disc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`type_of_classes` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_prepod` int(11) NOT NULL,
`index_group` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`disc_id`),
KEY `index_group` (`index_group`),
KEY `id_prepod` (`id_prepod`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

СREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exam` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`disc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`stud_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `disc_id` (`disc_id`),
KEY `stud_id` (`stud_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
`index_group` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`course` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_specialization` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`index_group`),
KEY `id_specialization` (`id_specialization`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
`stud_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`index_group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`stud_id`),
 KEY `index_group` (`index_group`),
 KEY `index_group_2` (`index_group`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением данной проблемы.

Comment: `group` - ключевое слово, если надо его использовать - обрамляйте его кавычками `\``: `select \`group\` ... from \`group\`` Или переименуйте поле/таблицу

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в обращении к таблице `group`. В MySQL слово `group` - зарезервированное слово (является частью синтаксиса `select ... group by`), и если надо его использовать в качестве имени для базы/таблицы/столбца - обрамляйте его специальными *обратными* кавычками:

```sql
select `group` ... from `group`
```

То же касается зарезервированных слов `select`, `insert`, `delete`, `update` (они обозначают действия, которые можно выполнить со строками), `text`, `date`, `time` (они обозначают типы данных) и [многих других](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#table-keywords-5.5-detailed).

Общей практикой и хорошим тоном будет *всегда* обрамлять названия базы/таблицы/столбца в запросах обратными кавычками, независимо от присутствия ключевых слов в этих названиях:

```sql
select `fldname` from `bdname`.`tblname` where `fld2name` = '123' order by `fld3name` limit 5
```

Comment: а еще не рекомендуется использовать *ключевые слова* в качестве имен.

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот заработало:

```
SELECT `group`.index_group, discipline.name_disc, COUNT(*), SUM(value)
FROM  `group`, discipline, exam, student
WHERE exam.stud_id = student.stud_id AND
exam.disc_id = discipline.disc_id AND
exam.value IS NOT NULL AND
exam.value > 2
GROUP BY `group`.index_group, discipline.name_disc
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код пожалуйста